# Show $\operatorname{tr} \nabla^2_{X,~\cdot} h(\cdot, W)= -(\nabla \delta h)(X,W)$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections, ricci-flow

I want to show
$$
\operatorname{tr} \nabla^2_{X,~\cdot} h(\cdot, W)= -(\nabla \delta h)(X,W)
$$
where $X,W$ are tangent vector fields on Riemannian manifold. And
$$
\nabla^2_{X,Y} = \nabla _X \nabla_Y - \nabla _{\nabla_XY}   
\\
\delta:\Gamma(\otimes^k T^* M) \rightarrow \Gamma(\otimes^{k-1} T^* M),~~~~
\delta(T)= -\operatorname{tr}_{12} (\nabla T).
$$

What I try:
$$
\operatorname{tr} \nabla^2_{X,~\cdot} h(\cdot, W) = g^{ij}\nabla ^2_{X, \partial_i} h(\partial_j, W)
\tag{1}
$$
Besides
\begin{align}
-(\nabla\delta h)(X,W)&=
[\nabla_X(\operatorname{tr}_{12}(\nabla h))] W \\
&=[\nabla_X (g^{ij} \nabla h(\partial_i, \partial_j, \cdot))]W \\
&=g^{ij} \nabla_X[\nabla h(\partial_i, \partial_j, \cdot)] W \\
&= g^{ij}[\nabla_X\nabla_{\partial_i } h(\partial_j, \cdot)-
\nabla_{\nabla_X\partial_i } h(\partial_j, \cdot)
-
\nabla_{\partial_i } h(\nabla_X\partial_j, \cdot)
] W\\
&=g^{ij}\nabla^2_{X, \partial_i} h(\partial_j, W) 
-
\nabla_{\partial_i } h(\nabla_X\partial_j, W)
\tag{2}
\end{align}
Obviously, (2) is not equal to (1). How should I do?

Comment: You should know $\nabla\partial_j=0$.

Comment: @user10354138  Thanks, in normal coordinate, it is right. I always forget to use normal coordinate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who wonder how this can be shown using the abstract index notation, here is a brief summary.

Rewrite both sides of the sought identity:
$$
\mathrm{tr} \nabla^2_{X,\cdot} h(\cdot, W) = g^{b c} X^a W^d \nabla_a \nabla_b h_{c d} = X^a W^d \nabla_a \nabla^c h_{c d} = X^a W^c \nabla_a \nabla^b h_{b c}
$$
and
$$
-(\nabla \delta h) (X, W) = X^a W^c \nabla_a \nabla^b h_{b c}
$$
so that the equality is simply read off from expanding the notation in abstract indices!

Here $g_{a b}$ is a Riemannian metric, $\nabla$ is the corresponding Levi-Civita connection, $\delta$ is the codifferential, which on a (tensor-bundle-valued) $k$-form $\omega_{a_1 \dots a_k}$ can be computed by the formula
$$
(\delta \omega)_{a_2 \dots a_k} = - \nabla^{a_1} \omega_{a_1 a_2 \dots a_k}
$$

We treat the $2$-tensor $h_{a b}$ as a $1$-form $h_a$ with values in the contagent bundle (with index $b$) in order to properly apply the above formula.

See similar calculations in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4286754/2002) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4287444/2002) answers.